# Elasticsearch index analyzers seem to do nothing after being added

Tags: elasticsearch

New to ES and following the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/languages.html) on using different analzers to deal with human language. After following some of the examples, it appears as though the added analyzers are having no effect on searches at all. Eg.

```
## init some index for testing
PUT /testindex
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "analysis": {},
    "refresh_interval": "1s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "testtype": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

## adding some analyzers for...
POST /testindex/_close
##... simple lowercase tokenization, ...(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/lowercase-token-filter.html#lowercase-token-filter)
PUT /testindex/_settings
{
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_lowercaser": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
}
## ... normalization (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/algorithmic-stemmers.html#_using_an_algorithmic_stemmer), ...
PUT testindex/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "english_stop": {
        "type":       "stop",
        "stopwords":  "_english_"
      },
      "light_english_stemmer": {
        "type":       "stemmer",
        "language":   "light_english" 
      },
      "english_possessive_stemmer": {
        "type":       "stemmer",
        "language":   "possessive_english"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "english": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "english_possessive_stemmer",
          "lowercase",
          "english_stop",
          "light_english_stemmer", 
          "asciifolding" 
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
## ... and using a hunspell dictionary (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hunspell.html#hunspell)
PUT testindex/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "en_US": {
        "type":     "hunspell",
        "language": "en_US" 
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "en_US": {
        "tokenizer":  "standard",
        "filter":   [ 
          "lowercase", 
          "en_US" 
          ]
      }
    }
  }
}
POST /testindex/_open
GET testindex/_settings
## it appears as though the analyzers have been added without problem

## adding some testing data
POST /testindex/testtype
{
  "title": "Will the root word of movement be found?"
}
POST /testindex/testtype
{
  "title": "That's why I never want to hear you say, ehhh I waant it thaaat away."
}

## expecting to match against root word of movement (move)
GET /testindex/testtype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "moving"
    }
  }
}
## which returns 0 hits, as shown below

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

## ... yet I can see that the record expected does in fact exist in the index when using...
GET /testindex/testtype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Thinking then that I need to actually "**add**" the analyzer to a (new) field, I do the following (which still shows negative results)

```
# adding the analyzers to a new field
POST /testindex/testtype
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "title2": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": [
            "my_lowercaser",
            "english",
            "en_US"
            ]
        }
      }
  }
}
# looking at the tokens I'd expect to be able to find
GET /testindex/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "en_US", 
  "text": "Moving between directories"
}
# moving, move, between, directory

# what I actually see
GET /testindex/_analyze
{
  "field": "title2", 
  "text": "Moving between directories"
}
# moving, between, directories
```

Even trying something simpler like

```
POST /testindex/testtype
    {
      "mappings": {
          "properties": {
            "title2": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "en_US"
            }
          }
      }
    }
```

does not help at all.

So this seems very messed up. Am I missing something here about how these analyzers are supposed to work? Should these analyzers be working properly (based on the provided info) and I am simply misusing them here? If so, could someone please provide an example query that would actually work/hit?

** Is there other debugging information that should be added here?

Comment: you can use `_analyze` endpoint to see how tokens are created. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN The problem is not that I don't know what the problem is (I have a pretty good idea of what I should be seeing), but that it seems that the analyzers are having no effect at all. In any case, have added another example that uses the endpoint you described for extra info.

Answer (score 1):

`title2` field has 3 analyzers, but according to your output(`analyze` endpoint) it seems that only `my_lowercaser` is applied.

Finally, the config that worked for me with `hunspell` is:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "en_US": {
          "type":     "hunspell",
          "language": "en_US" 
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "en_US": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter":   [ "lowercase", "en_US" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }

"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title-en-us": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "en_US"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`movement` is not resolved to `move` while `moving` is(probably `hunspell` dictionary related). Querying with `move` resulted in docs with `moving` only, but not `movement`.

Comment: "title2 field has 3 analyzers, but ... seems that only my_lowercaser is applied." Yes, that is the problem. I don't know why this is happening though. Never used ES until now, so I don't understand what exactly you are trying to say to do in the second part of your answer (I thought I had already done what you are showing in my question output).

Comment: Suggesting to use a one analyzer per field, if you want to use multiple analyzers, check out multi-fields: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers